# OpenSSH Won't Start on Ubuntu EC2 Instance

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

My Amazon EC2 instance's openssh server fails on boot ever since I scaled my instance.

I have tried following these instructions here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14026148/running-ec2-instance-suddenly-refuses-ssh-connection

I have detached my EBS volume and attached it to a new instance of the same OS in the same region. I can see that there are two volumes attached to it before I start it up.

Once it starts, it experiences the exact same problem my other instance is experiencing where I cannot SSH into it.

I then detach the "bad" volume and reboot the instance and it works as expected.

What am I doing incorrectly that is causing the instance OS to run openssh off of the "bad" volume instead of the new volume associated with it as the root volume?

Comment: What do the ssh logs say?

Comment: I can't see them because I can't access the server through SSH to read them. I get "connection refused" when attempting to connect. I looked at the AWS system log and it shows openssh trying to start about 8 times and then failing.

Comment: Well there's really nothing any of us can do to help you other than suggesting that you either 1) Re-build a new server from the ground up, mount your current EBS volume to the new server, and restore your data or 2) Mount the current EBS vol to a new server and fix up whatever's broken.

Comment: Since you "scaled" your instance?  What specifically did you change?